# Gatling/JMeter record scenario incompletely

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, jmeter, load-testing, gatling

I've been using JMeter and Gatling to record a scenario on a JSF2 PrimeFaces 4 web app, in order to load test it. The recording goes well with both tools, but the replay of the scenario fails because a click action on a commandButton opening a popup dialog doesn't fire the associated event. Said commandButton gets enabled by the previous action in the scenario (a dropDown selection in the same table row).

That issue happens only when running the scenario on the performance testing tools, not when navigating in the browser UI.

I've compared the arguments of the POST requests picked up by Firebug and Gatling/JMeter, and they seem completely identical (management of the JSF ViewState is correctly set up btw). I've also increased the pauses between actions during the scenario, but to no avail.

Any ideas on what the recorders and/or I could be missing?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Neither Gatling nor JMeter executes javascript, so if you have some javascript logic, you'll have to re-implement it.

Comment: Thanks Stéphane, but how come the POST request associated with the clic doesn't fire the event ?

Comment: So all the requests you expect are properly recorded? Then are you sure you don't have some kind of session token you have to properly capture and send?

Comment: The recording process triggers the creation of a POST request that seems to bear the correct arguments. The commandButton has a listener invoking a patameterized event (parameter is the current table row, i.e. the table var). The session token to transmit is the JSF ViewState, and it is dealt with using a regex extractor each time a request is sent.

Comment: You'd have to show your scenario code and exactly point to what doesn't work exactly.

Comment: Well, the actual POST action from the gatling test plan is huge, considering it sends parameters for each input in the form, it takes about 130 lines...

Comment: JSF my love... It would probably be easier if you joined the Gatling GGroup and post a gist.

Answer (score 0):

@Cleverback I've got some examples with Primefaces and Gatling here: https://github.com/rmpestano/gatling-jsf-demo and also there is an example of JSF event.

Can you create or describe your case as a test case on that project?